# Emulated NFC tag not read by android app in android 5

Tags: android, arduino, nfc, hce

I am using a NFC shield (model: PN532 RFID/NFC Shield) that reads NFC tags that are emulated on android phones (using HCE-host card emulation). After the tag is read the NFC shield emulates a tag so that an application on the phone can read it. I have written an android application that emulates an NFC tag and waits for an NFC tag/message. This process works on Android 4.4, but not on android 5 and up. The phone either doesn't see the tag(the one being emulated by the NFC shield) or says it is not supported(the tag is supposed to be supported seeing that it is a universal supported one).

In my manifest I have the following intent:

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
```

In my oncreate method I use the following code:

```
    mAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);

    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this, 0, new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
    IntentFilter ndef = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
    try {
        ndef.addDataType("text/plain");    /* Handles all MIME based dispatches.
                                   You should specify only the ones that you need. */
    }
    catch (IntentFilter.MalformedMimeTypeException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("fail", e);
    }
    intentFiltersArray = new IntentFilter[] {ndef, };

    this.onNewIntent(this.getIntent());
```

Is this correct or do I need a different implementation for android 5 and up?

Comment: If your emulated tag does not properly work, I would suggest that you post the relevant code that *emulates that tag* (hence, the code on the Arduino side).

Comment: I recommend testing your 'emulated tag' with [this excellent android tool](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nxp.taginfolite).

Comment: And `NfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch()`, [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html) _might_ change something...